# Cumulative sum of an unique only variable with attached condition

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

This is what my dataframe looks like. The rightmost column is my desired column. I am trying to get cumulative sum of unique FundTypes when the ActivityType is Sale. So the first row has an activitytype == email, therefore there is no cumulative sum, same for second row, the third row has activitytype == sale and it should show cumulative sum as 1 because the condition is satisfied.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('
Name      ActivityType     FundType  UniqueFundsSale(Desired) 
John       Email               a            0                    
John       Webinar             b            0                   
John       Sale                a            1                   
John       Sale                b            2                     
John       Webinar             c            2                     
John       Sale                a            2                     
John       Sale                b            2                     
John       Sale                c            3                     
Tom        Email               a            0                    
Tom        Webinar             b            0                   
Tom        Sale                a            1                   
Tom        Sale                b            2                     
Tom        Webinar             c            2                     
Tom        Sale                a            2                     
Tom        Sale                b            2                     
Tom        Sale                c            3')
```

I have tried the following.

```
dt[, UniqueFundsSale := 
  cumsum(ActivityType=="Sale" & !duplicated(FundType,ActivityType) & !FundType=="")
, by = Name]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Fyi, you can `fread("text text text")` to construct an example, too.

Comment: @Frank Thank you Frank. I did not know that. So i can construct an example using fread and directly post it to stackoverflow?

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit it in to demonstrate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way (thanks to @eddi for simplifications):

```
w = dt[ActivityType == "Sale", .I[1L], by = .(Name, FundType)]$V1
dt[, new_col := cumsum(.I %in% w), by = Name]
```

The closest analogue in base R is probably

```
dt$idx = seq_len(nrow(dt))
w = with(dt[dt$ActivityType == "Sale"], 
  c(tapply(idx, list(Name, FundType), FUN = `[`, 1L)))
dt$new_col = ave(dt$idx, dt$Name, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x %in% w))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!